# Android - Displaying a static activity within another static activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

Disclaimer: I am brand new to Android and just finding my way - `Fragments` confuse the hell out of me.

I'm working on building a little resume app that will eventually have a tab layout. For now I'm working on the front page which will display a header with an image and a name, then a TextView with a short summary statement, and underneath a list of "core skills". In trying to add a `ListView` to my `MainActivity.java` I keep running into the same problem - it pastes itself over all my other elements rather than appearing at the bottom.

Is there any way I can get the `ListView` to just appear at the bottom without using a `Fragment`? And if I do have to use a `Fragment`, what is some simple code to just have a static list there?

```js
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ArrayList<String[]> coreSkills = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //set the content view of the activity
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //set a text view for the Summary
        TextView profileSummary = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.summary_text);
        profileSummary.setText(R.string.profile_summary);

        String[] coreSkills = {
                "Android Development",
                "GitHub",
                "Skill",
                "Skill",
                "Skill",
                "Skill"
        };

        ArrayAdapter<String> coreSkillsAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.core_skills_list,
                        R.id.skill_name, coreSkills);

        ListView coreSkillsList = new ListView(this);
        setContentView(coreSkillsList);
        coreSkillsList.setAdapter(coreSkillsAdapter);

    }
}
```

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_info_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_face_white_48dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/photo"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Your Name"
            android:textColor="@color/textWhite"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_info_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/summary_heading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Summary"
            android:textColor="@color/textBlack"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/summary_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/textBlack"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/core_skills_heading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Core Skills"
            android:textColor="@color/textBlack"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/core_skills_list" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm working with two layout files because my app crashes on launch when I try to have all this information running through `activity_main.xml`. Both files are `LinearLayouts` with nested children.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not adding the list view to a fragment. You're replacing the activity's content view with the list view.

```
setContentView(coreSkillsList);
```

In this case, you don't really need a fragment. You can do something like this instead:

Add a `ListView` view at the end of your `activity_main` layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    ....

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/my_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And access it in your activity like this:

```
....
ListView coreSkillsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
coreSkillsList.setAdapter(coreSkillsAdapter);
....
```

Comment: That fixed it! I had tried to add a ListView in the xml at some point but what happened then was that each list item would replicate the **entire** layout - I'd get header, summary, list item; header, summary, list item etc.
If you wouldn't mind: your ListView snippet is the same as mine except minus setContentView. What does removing that achieve, exactly? It worked, I'm just confused as to why.
Thanks again!

Comment: @IronAnneBonnie You were probably creating multiple `ListView` views.

Comment: @IronAnneBonnie `setContentView` sets the activity's layout. The changes that I've made adds the list view to the activity's layout instead of setting it as the activity's layout.